# Can Matillion ETL convert multiple CSV files to Parquet?

Tags: matillion

I have the following folder hierarchy in an S3 bucket:

January/10
16b516c0-8f2a-eabd-770a-b8bbc83c5859.csv, 16b516c0-8f2a-eabd-770a-b8bbc83c5859.csv, …

In other words, every folder represents a calendar day.
I would like Matillion ETL to do the following transform:
January/10
AsingleParquetFile.Parquet

How can I implements this in Matillion ETL?

Answer (score 0):

Matillion ETL would do this by using the CDW it's attached to. The exact answer would depend which CDW you are using, but would typically involve an external table and an unload component.

For example using Matillion ETL for Redshift:

[image]

followed by:

[image]